# How to write SQL query inside else statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to find if query does not return any results, then print 'no records found' else execute the query.

Here is my query,

```
select case when exists (
   SELECT CAST(dm.[ID] AS VARCHAR(100)) as ID, case when dm.[Que_Type] = 0 then 'Valid' else 'Invalid' end [Type],
   dm.[Name_List], t.[Name], dm.[FromDate], dm.[ToDate] FROM tblDays dm(nolock)
   inner join (select pr.ID, pr.name from tblProduct pr(nolock)) as t
   on dm.TradeID = t.ID where 1=1 and dm.ToDate between GETDATE() and DATEADD(dd, 15, GETDATE()))
then 'ok'
else 'no records'
end
```

In this query, I want to execute the query instead of printing 'ok'. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an `if` statement along with `exists`

Since the conditional check is just to see if any records are returned, there is no need to select all those columns, so we just `select 1`. If records are found, the `if` tests true, and we'll run the sql statement. If no records are found, we'll drop to the else block and `print 'no records'`.

This may work for you:

```
IF(
   exists(
            select 1 
            FROM tblDays dm(nolock)
            inner join (select pr.ID, pr.name from tblProduct pr(nolock)) as t
                on dm.TradeID = t.ID 
            where 1=1 
            and dm.ToDate between GETDATE() and DATEADD(dd, 15, GETDATE())
          )
   )
BEGIN
    SELECT  CAST(dm.[ID] AS VARCHAR(100)) as ID
            , case when dm.[Que_Type] = 0 then 'Valid' else 'Invalid' end [Type]
            , dm.[Name_List]
            , t.[Name]
            , dm.[FromDate]
            , dm.[ToDate] 
    FROM tblDays dm(nolock)
        inner join (select pr.ID, pr.name from tblProduct pr(nolock)) as t
            on dm.TradeID = t.ID 
    where 1=1 
    and dm.ToDate between GETDATE() and DATEADD(dd, 15, GETDATE())
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    print 'no records'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `@@ROWCOUNT`:

According to [**BOL**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx):

> Returns the number of rows affected by the last statement.

```
SELECT 
    CAST(dm.[ID] AS VARCHAR(100)) AS ID, 
    CASE WHEN dm.[Que_Type] = 0 THEN 'Valid' ELSE 'Invalid' END AS [Type],
    dm.[Name_List], 
    t.[Name],
    dm.[FromDate],
    dm.[ToDate]
FROM tblDays dm(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        pr.ID,
        pr.name 
    FROM tblProduct pr(NOLOCK)
) AS t
    ON dm.TradeID = t.ID 
WHERE 
    1 = 1 
    AND dm.ToDate BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(dd, 15, GETDATE())

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
   PRINT 'No records found.'
```